# NodeJS iteration takes too long

Tags: javascript, node.js, csv

I have a few routes which do the following :
on upload route:
Accepts CSV file(200K Rows) > Save it in Postgres temporary table inside amazon s3 bucket > Save it in Postgres permanent table .

fetch route:
Fetch both rows array of each table (tmp + table) > iterate over each for simple process (for comparison between rows feature)
the problem is that the first iteration takes more than hour waiting to finish the iteration so my nodejs will not be able to finish task and send a response to the client.
any suggestions?

Comment: even the most simple forEach method takes alot

Comment: 200k rows is a lot and it will take a lot of time

Comment: Pre-process the information and store it in a separate memory so you won't have to process the info every time. If your information is highly dynamic... I'm afraid that there is no solution other than to upgrade your computing power

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Fast way to iterate - [pg-iterator](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-iterator) might be of help ;)